# PHP - Create Text file on mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to Create a text file with MySQL database errors because I never get to see the page.

```
mysql_query(
"INSERT INTO cart (value1) VALUES ('value1')", $link) 
or die(mysql_error());
```

But I want to replace the mysql_error into a text file, any thoughts?

Comment: I see you're new to Stack Overflow. Be sure to give the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) a read if you haven't already, and be sure to select an answer to your question once you've found what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

you can put your function in **die()**

```
 or die(your_function(mysql_error()))

 function your_function(e){
    file_put_contents('log.txt', e);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create text file on MySQL error and log MySQL error in it.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

$db = mysql_select_db("nonexistentdb", $link);
if(!$db) {
  $err = mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link). "\n";
  $file = fopen('filename.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($file, $err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to write the mysql_error() to a log file.

```
$file = fopen('mysql_error.log','a');
mysql_query($query)
```

or

```
die(fwrite($file1,"$query".mysql_error(). "\n"));
```

This will write the query and the error on the same line of the log file.